# Ubuntu 14.04 terminal glitch

Tags: 14.04, command-line, unity-dash

I was installing Maya 2015 on Ubuntu 14.04, and as soon as I got to the command "for i in *.rpm; do sudo alien -cv $i;", as suggested [here](http://forums.autodesk.com/t5/installation-licensing/installing-maya-on-ubuntu/td-p/4905036/highlight/false), the next line appears pretty much blank, except for one closing angle bracket (>), and any command I ran did nothing whatsoever. Please help me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "`>`" prompt appears because the shell expects you to continue the `for` loop or close it using the word "`done`".

In your case you just have to add `done` at the end of the line or after the `>` prompt, e.g.

```
for i in *.rpm; do sudo alien -cv $i; done
```

This is an error in the instructions.